# How to manually update Entity framework Code first model so that it updates a database (with a new column)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

can somebody tell me how I can add a data member (col) to my mvc3 model (class) and have it update the database without having to generate everything from scratch?  I'm working from code first.  When I change my model then run my project I get an error stating that model has changed.  Any clean and easy way to synch creating a new col/data mamber with the db/model?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an MVC3 question it an Entity Framework code first question.

Comment: I think it's largely a case of adding the new field, right clicking in Visual Studio and choosing the update item, as you're using Code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this in application start,

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDBContext>());
```

it will regenerate the database if your model change happens.And if you do not want to drop and create database (To incremental development) you can use SqlMigrations. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx

Comment: What if I have data in there database?

Comment: you can use the second method. It will not recreate the database. Or else you can have your own initializer which create database and insert basic data (or execute script )when regenerating. Read this answer .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881509/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-and-permanent-table-in-database/6881627#6881627

Comment: The SqlMigrations package is awesome. Thanks for the link, Jayantha!