# How to synch Model with Database after code first using EF4.1and MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manually update Entity framework Code first model so that it updates a database (with a new column)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100578/how-to-manually-update-entity-framework-code-first-model-so-that-it-updates-a-dat)

Can somebody please tell me how I can add a new field to a class (my model) and have it update my database *after* I have already created the database using entiry framework 4.1 and mvc3?

I realize that I can set the following:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ImpressiionTrackerContext>());
```

but I don't won't my data deleted from the database.

Also if I update my database (add a column to an existing table) *after* I have already created the database using entity framework 4.1 and mvc3...how can I synch my model with the changes (new col) I made to the DB...and keep the data that is already in the database?

I'm pretty new to EF so I will submit to ridicule here but I have yet to find an elegant solution that keeps the existing data around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using code-first and changing your model during development it is better to have some dummy data in your creation method until you have your model set in stone.

You could also generate some data scripts and run them after you regenerate the database although this isn't an automatic process, you would have to do it manually or build it into your application.